# How to remove object with specific name from ArrayList

Tags: c#, arraylist

I have ArrayList with some objects. My code dynamically adding objects to this ArrayList. For example, my code adding to ArrayList some buttons.

I have some buttons in ArrayList with different names. I want just one button in ArrayList with specific name.

I need something like this:

```
if (arrayList.Contains(button.Name = "button1"))
{
    arrayList.Remove(button.Name = "button1");
}
```

But this code doesn't work.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Don't use `ArrayList` anymore. It belongs old times when C# doesn't support _generics_. Use `List<T>` instead..

Comment: Ok.
But it doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arrayList = arrayList.Where(x=>x.Name != "button1").ToList();
```